# Summing outputs from a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
 case [Group]
  when 1 then 'in'
  when 0 then 'out'
  end as traffic

 FROM [GW_Test_Back_Up].[dbo].[ARC_Calls_ReportView]
```

Which creates a new column with many rows containing in/out for traffic, but what I really want is only two rows, one for the sum of the in's and the other for the sum of the out's.  I am stuck on how I would do this.

Comment: Two rows or two columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe you are after:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN [Group] = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS InCount,
SUM(CASE WHEN [Group] = 0 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS OutCount
 FROM [GW_Test_Back_Up].[dbo].[ARC_Calls_ReportView]
```

Or maybe this:

```
SELECT 'InCount' AS Type,
SUM(CASE WHEN [Group] = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS InCount
FROM [GW_Test_Back_Up].[dbo].[ARC_Calls_ReportView]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'OutCount' AS Type,
SUM(CASE WHEN [Group] = 0 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS OutCount
FROM [GW_Test_Back_Up].[dbo].[ARC_Calls_ReportView]
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN m.InCount > 10 THEN 'High' ELSE 'Low' END AS InCountStatus
CASE WHEN m.OutCount > 10 THEN 'High' ELSE 'Low' END AS OutCountStatus
FROM 
(
   SELECT
     SUM(CASE WHEN [Group] = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS InCount,
     SUM(CASE WHEN [Group] = 0 then 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS OutCount
   FROM [GW_Test_Back_Up].[dbo].[ARC_Calls_ReportView]
) m
```

Comment: Both ways work fine, thank you.  Now how about if I am more interested in using InCount and OutCount as variables later in the query and I don't need to actually display them in the table. Like if OutCount is > 100 do something.....

Comment: @eltel2910, see my edit for a sample of how to work with the `InCount`and `OutCount`.  You will have to wrap the query in another query to access them by the alias.

Comment: what RDBMS are you using, so I can tag this question properly.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  RDBMS = MS SQL Server